# Isomorphism between ordered sets.

Tags: order-theory

If (A,<1) and (B,<2) are ordered sets such that is (A,<1) is isomorphic to an initial segment of (B,<2) and (B,<2) is isomorphic to an end segment of (A,<1), then (A,<1) and (B,<2) are isomorphic.

I tried to use Cantor-Bernstein Theorem, but I do not think isomorphism between the  ordered sets follows from isomorphic embedding in both sides.
How can I prove it?

Comment: If by "ordered set" you mean "totally ordered set", then it is straightforward to adapt Konig's proof of the Cantor-Bernstein Theorem to this situation.